# how to design iphone pages in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i have done sharepoint project. now client need to view same project in ipad. but the problem is when client try to open the web pages, the request time out. so how to compress my web pages so easily open in ipad browser. i have removed all the css but i had still face the same issue. is there any tips to develop web page for iphone.